# Probability of finding a specific colored plant in a row.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, probability-limit-theorems

In a packet of flower seeds 3/4 are yellow flowering and rest are white. If 200 rows of each plants are planted, how many will contain
(i) all yellow flowers.
(ii) all white flowers
(iii) two yellow and two white flowers

Comment: So you now assume that a "row" is four flowers? Also, what do you mean by " 200 rows of **each plants**"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you mean a row is four flowers, and that the order on a row is not important. Then each row may be one in $5$ outcomes:

- (#yellow, #white) = {(4,0), (3,1), (2,2), (1,3), (0,4)}

If you bag of seeds is infinitely big, then taking a seed will not change the stated probabilities. Thus, we may use the binomial distribution.

The probabilities for all yellow and all white are pretty trivial, namely $0.75^4 = 0.3164$ and $0.25^4 = 0.0039$ respectively.

The probability of 2 of each is found by the binomial distribution:
$\binom{2}{4} 0.75^2 0.25^2 = 0.2109$.

Out of 200 rows you simply multiply each probability by 200, then you will see the *expected* number of rows of each kind.

**This may not be what you are looking for, as the question is very ambiguous...**